# Web Project Not Starting in Websphere 9 with CDI related Exception for BValInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, maven, websphere, websphere-9

I'm trying to Start Web Project in Websphere 9, however I'm getting Runtime Exceptions realted CDI
Note: The Project is working in WAS 8.5 but after migrating to WAS 9, I'm getting this issue.

I have also used these properties to disable CDI. However I'm still not able to start the Web Application.
**com.ibm.ws.cdi.enableImplicitBeanArchives = false** and **com.ibm.ws.cdi.enableCDI = false**

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

```
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)

[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:809)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1421)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2232)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5398)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5614)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1311)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:827 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:608)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:828 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1386)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:195)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1234)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:477)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:970)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:517)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:338)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:961)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:294)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:829 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)

[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1187)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:786)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     ... 89 more
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)

[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.start(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:404)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.stateChanged(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:488)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:830 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$ComparableDeployedObjectListener.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2551)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1497)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.setState(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:310)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1087)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     ... 90 more
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)

[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.applicationStarting(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:333)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.cdi.classic.CDIRuntimeImpl.start(CDIRuntimeImpl.java:391)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     ... 96 more
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)

[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInterceptor(Validator.java:556)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$2.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:85)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$2.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:83)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:831 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:832 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[1/27/20 12:28:24:832 EST] 000000eb SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to fix the issue by myself. Here's the approach I used:

I have these projects in my workspace: **MyApp-Ear**, **MyApp-Web**, **MyApp-Jar**.

I added the configuration in the MyApp-Ear Module then it worked like Magic. I used Maven Manfiest entries in ***maven-ear-plugin*** inside the configuration tag.

```
<configuration>
    --------------
    <archive>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Enable-Implicit-Bean-Archive>false</Enable-Implicit-Bean-Archive>
            <Enable-CDI>false</Enable-CDI>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

***Note:*** There were other approaches that I used however they didn't work for me:

1: added the Properties in serverName>Process definition > Environment Entries

2: added the Properties in Enterprise Applications > EAR_Project> Custom properties